# Revert to Old CSS on mouseout in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I am using following function to set CSS Styles on a TAG:

```
function setStyle (styles = {}, tag){
    let key;
    for (key in styles) {
        if (!styles.hasOwnProperty(key))
           continue;
        tag.style[key] = styles[key];
    }
    return tag;
}
```

I have created another function which will apply new CSS Style on mouseover and revert to old CSS on mouseout:

```
function hoverCss(styleSet = {}, tag) {
        const oldCss = tag.style;

        tag.onmouseover = () => {
            // console.info('APPLY NEW CSS');
            setStyle(styleSet, tag);
        };

        tag.onmouseleave = () => {
            // console.info('RESTORE OLD CSS');
            setStyle(oldCss, tag);
        };

        return tag;
    }
```

When I execute the above code, New CSS is applying on Mouse Over, but old CSS is not applying back when Mouse Leave. Please provide a solution for this bug.

**EDIT**

The rest of the code to call the functions looks like this:

```
const tag = document.getElementById('someId');
hoverCss({color:'red'}, tag);
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Why not just have two different classes and toggle the applied class on the element? This way seems so much more complicated and less efficient.

Comment: Could you provide more details like styles object for the new css and old css and when you called this method `hoverCss`

Comment: @JeremyHarris, I don't want to use CSS, or any jQuery, just pure JavaScript

Comment: @AhmedKesha, please see the EDIT. Thanks

Comment: just change to onmouseout

Comment: @MateusMartins, Same. There is nothing wrong in calling. I can print messages on console logs through both, tag.onmouseover & tag.onmouseleave.

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal check my answer I moved your oldCss object outside the hover function

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal right, but when listening to `mouseout`, you´ll get all out events including childs, the same behavior as `mouseover`

Comment: @MateusMartins, Yes. But it doesn't solve the problem. CSS is still not reverting to it's original form

Comment: @AhmedKesha, please see my comment on your answer. Thanks

Comment: maybe it's happening cause objects in JS works as reference, try copying the styles object on `const oldCss = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tag.style))`

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal I updated my answer to make it more generic

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal take a look at my new answer, think it will solve your problemn

Answer (score 1):

Think this is best achieved with pure css

```
.element {
  // Add your element styles here
}

.element:hover {
 // Add styles here to be applied when element is hovered over
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use CSS. I want to achieve it through pure JAVAScript. No Framworks like jQuery etc. should be used.

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal You will be setting the style property of a DOM element, which is equivalent to setting the CSS itself, so why not do that directly?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava, the code on which I am working requires CSS editing through DOM only. That's the client requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this syntax

```js
target.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  setStyle(oldCss, tag);
});
```

Comment: Not working. There is nothing wrong in calling. I can print messages on console logs through both, tag.onmouseover & tag.onmouseleave. The problem lies somewhere in Style object. May be I'm not implementing Old CSS properly, that's I want to figure out

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your oldCss object outside the function hover like this to solve your issue

```
        function setStyle(styles = {}, tag) {
        console.log(styles);
        let key;
        for (key in styles) {
            if (!styles.hasOwnProperty(key))
                continue;
            tag.style[key] = styles[key];
        }
        return tag;
    }

    function hoverCss(styleSet = {}, tag) {
        elementStyle = tag.style;
        oldCss = {}
        var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(tag, null);
        // get the default css as object and keep it 
        for (prop in elementStyle) {
            if (elementStyle.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                oldCss[prop] = elementStyle[prop];
            }
        }
        // If the newCss has something isn't in the oldcss so keep that as empty
        for (let property in styleSet) {
            if (!oldCss.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                oldCss[property] = '';
            }
        }
        tag.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            setStyle(styleSet, this);
        });

        tag.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
            setStyle(oldCss, this);
        });

        return tag;
    }

    const tag = document.getElementById('someId');
    hoverCss({ color: 'red' }, tag);
```

I understand you are going with this way maybe because you need to control your css using JS

Comment: Yes you are right. I need to control CSS through JS. Your solution is good, but it's limited. It's good when we know which tag requires what CSS. But my Code is completely unknown of TAG. It can a be any tag, with any CSS Styles. So it should be written in an Universal Implementation, so that it can be used with any tag.

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal I updated my answer to make it more generic to get the old css and keep it to return it again and keep track the new properties in the newCss to remove them when mouseout

Answer (score 0):

This behavior because js threats object per reference, so, when you do `const oldCss = tag.style`, the `oldCss` object points to the same memory address as `tag.style`

So when you change some attribute on `tag.style` it changes for `oldCss` to, the const declaration just says that you cannot change the oldCss value, not it´s childs

You'll have to do `const oldCss = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tag.style))` to avoid the reference behavior